# How to get two different properties from an edge and a vertex under the same result using by() step?

Tags: titan, gremlin, tinkerpop

[image]If a professor is working in three departments and he need to retrieve the department name and experience, In which experience is present on the edge.I need to retrieve both department name and experience as a group?

If I am using choose step it is giving result

```
g.V().has('personId','1cdbdcf4-9223-37a9-ad6f-70875dbadc37')
.union(constant(true)
,identity().out('favourite')
.as('professor',"distance","experience")
.select('professor',"distance","experience")
.by(__.valueMap('professerId','Name','rating','imageUrl').fold())
.by(identity().out('PrimaryAddress')
.map({it.get().value('geoPoint').getPoint()
.distance(Geoshape.point(new BigDecimal(17.364426),new BigDecimal(78.38968)).getPoint())}))
.by(identity().outE('areaOfExpertise')
.choose(label).option('areaOfExpertise'
,identity()
.as('areaOfExpertise','subject')
.select('areaOfExpertise','subject')
.by(values('teachingSince').fold())
.by(inV().valueMap('SubjectName')))
.fold()))
.unfold()
```

If I am not using choose step

```
g.V().has('personId','1cdbdcf4-9223-37a9-ad6f-70875dbadc37')
.union(constant(true)
,identity().out('favourite')
.as('professor',"distance","experience")
.select('Professor',"distance","experience")
.by(__.valueMap('professorId','Name','rating','imageUrl').fold())
.by(identity().out('PrimaryAddress')
.map({it.get().value('geoPoint').getPoint()
.distance(Geoshape.point(new BigDecimal(17.364426),new BigDecimal(78.38968)).getPoint())}))
.by(identity().outE('areaOfExpertise')
.as('areaOfExpertise','problem')
.select('areaOfExpertise','subject')
.by(values('teachingSince').fold())
.by(inV().valueMap('subjectName'))
.fold()))
.unfold()
```

It is returning "java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.structure.Element"

Comment: Your queries are doing a lot more work than what the diagram shows. If you could simplify your queries to focus in on the specific question you are asking and supply some example data, that would be helpful.

Comment: the query is to get the favorites of a person , the favorites are professors

Comment: the query is to get the favorites of a person , the favorites are professors i want the professors (professerId,name,rating , imageurl)  which i would get with( __.valueMap())     along with the distance from persons location to his primary address which iam getting with the groovy collection and distance function  . I also want to get the experience info  of the professor which is the combined value of his area of expertise and the date he started teaching in that subject am  using the by() step which has  two intenal by steps so that i can fold them into an object

Comment: i am using nested by() for folding the two properties teaching since and subject name into one result . am doing this as there may be more than one area of expertise to a professor

Comment: in addition to what @JasonPlurad wrote you might also consider formatting your Gremlin a bit so that it's easier to read - scrolling through those one-liners is pretty hard to do: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/recipes/#style-guide

Comment: there might me an issue with the 3rd by() step which a you are using to get "exp" as it is must that by returns only a single result